# MYSQL Get id from Table1 and Insert to Table2 while INSERTING Values (USER Form)

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-insert

I have 2 tables:

Table1

```
u_id    email
1       user1@y.com
2       user2@h.com
```

and
Table2

```
id u_id values
```

had to insert values to table2 with u_id when user enters from form
Example:I need to add the value table1 u_id while that user is logged in into table2 that is id increments in table and u_id from table1 and values as user enters from table2

i tried something this query however not successful

```
insert into table2 (u_id,values)
            values ((select u_id from table1), 'values')
```

Comment: I removed the `sql-server` tag, since the question title mentions `mysql`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your query is that the subquery returns multiple rows (one value per row in `table1`), while the database expects a scalar value.

I would expect that you know the `email` of the current user, and want to recover the corresponding `u_id` to `insert` a new row in `table2`, along with a literal value. If so, I would recommend the `insert ... select` syntax:

```
insert into table2 (u_id, val)
select u_id, 'foo' from table1 where email = 'user1@y.com'
```

Side note: `values` is a SQL keyword, hence not a good choice for a column name (you would need to quote this identifier every time you use it). I renamed this column to `val` in the query.

Comment: where is foo from . i mean what is that @GMB , Also im using session in php so i can write $email where email ='$email';

Comment: @rsethi:  (1) `'foo'` is whatever fixed value you want to insert in column `val` (you can change it as per your requirement). (2) Yes, you should pass the user email as a parameter to the query (note that you you would better use a parameterized query rather than concatenating the parameter in the query string) .

Comment: how would you do parameterized query can you provide some example keeping in mind the same. I am newbie here

Comment: @rsethi: there are lot of resources that you can find on the web, by searching for something like *php parameterized query*. You could start with [this famous SO post)[https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/10676716].